# Multi line vbs auto typer from .txt file

Tags: vbscript

So i have been working on a troll terminal and now i want to type out the entire bee movie script or whatever i put in a text file.
What i need help with is taking the text(with enters and spaces) and fully typing it out.
Another way to say it is i want to take a text file and copy it threw typing it out.
I couldnt find any decent code to do this wich is why i'm asking here.

Also if possible make it type anything that you put in the text file.
`(I have no clue why it doesnt let me post this)`

Idea: I might know another way around but i dont know how to get it done.
Maby there is a way to infinetly generate variables for each line and type them out like that.

Other idea: I might be able to make a tool to let me quickly hard code it.

Comment: Fixed why it didnt let me post.

Comment: No, i m looking for multi line. Still thanks tho.

Comment: @smvd Have you checked the answer to that question or you've just read the question header? It contains the solution.

Comment: It contains most of the solution i need but my respons was incorrect cuz me during class not have big brain. I understand how to type the thing i need help with is taking a text file for example the entire urban dictionary and setting to a string that the send key command will properly translate

Comment: @eyllanesc i m so sorry i did a smol brain and made a huge mistake please excuse me for not being smart. Your actual edit was fully correct. (I will delete any comment i made that included the mistake exept this one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\yourfirstfile", 1)
content = file.ReadAll

Const fsoForAppend = 8

Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Open the text file
Dim objTextStream
Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\yoursecondfile", fsoForAppend)

'Display the contents of the text file
objTextStream.WriteLine content 


'Close the file and clean up
objTextStream.Close
Set objTextStream = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
wshShell.run "C:\yoursecondfile"
```

Tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

Yes i m self anwsering.

This script works but it double taps enter i will update it if i figure out how to stop that from happening.

```
Set wsh=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sub custom_text_typer_confirm
Set objFileToRead =WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("Custom_Text_Typer.txt",1)
strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
objFileToRead.Close
custom_typer_wait = inputbox("How long should the program wait untill it will start typing?", "Eclips-Terminal Custom Text Typer")
custom_typer_wait1=custom_typer_wait * 1000
Wscript.sleep custom_typer_wait1
wsh.sendkeys (strFileText & "{enter}")
Wscript.sleep 1000
call home
end sub
```

Comment: I see you have been using wsh.Sendkeys. Honestly, I would recommend  appending into a file instead of using sendkeys.

Comment: The reason i use sendkeys is to use it in discord, whatsapp etc.. But if you didnt need it that would be the better option.

Comment: Oh ok. I understand.